# Reading rain data from a txt file in Python 3

Tags: scipy, python-3.4

I'm new using Python 3.4 and I'll be using it for my internship in the next month. However, my instructor gave me a task to practice while I haven't started it yet. Thus, he gave me a set of data and he asked me to figure how to load this out. However, it keep showing me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
   raindata = loadtxt('slz_chuva.txt', comments='#', delimiter=',')
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in loadtxt
   items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 848, in <listcomp>
   items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'A203'
```

and this is my code:

```
from scipy import loadtxt

raindata = loadtxt('slz_chuva.txt', comments='#', delimiter= ',')
```

and this is my data:

## codigo_estacao,data,hora,temp_inst,temp_max,temp_min,umid_inst,umid_max,umid_min,pto_orvalh#o_inst,pto_orvalho_max,pto_orvalho_min,pressao,pressao_max,pressao_min,vento_direcao,vento_vel,vento_rajada,radiacao,precipitacao

A203,09/05,2014,00,24.8,24.8,24.5,95,95,94,23.9,24.0,23.7,1006.3,1006.3,1005.7,0.3,24,1.8,-3.08,0.0
A203,09/05/2014,01,24.5,24.8,24.5,95,95,95,23.7,24.0,23.7,1006.9,1006.9,1006.3,0.0,30,1.7,-2.78,0.0
A203,09/05/2014,02,24.6,24.6,24.4,96,96,95,23.8,23.8,23.7,1006.6,1006.9,1006.6,0.3,42,1.7,-2.86,0.0
A203,09/05/2014,03,24.8,25.0,24.5,96,96,95,24.1,24.2,23.8,1006.2,1006.6,1006.2,0.0,51,1.8,-1.70,0.0

Could someone help me out?

thanks

Comment: Should the 1st line have `09/05,2014` (others have /)?

Answer (score 0):

Correct the first date, and use `recfromcsv`

```
In [40]: sp.recfromcsv('stack23785259.txt')
Out[40]: 
rec.array([ ('A203', '09/05/2014', 0, 24.8, 24.8, 24.5, 95, 95, 94, 23.9, 24.0, 23.7, 1006.3, 1006.3, 1005.7, 0.3, 24, 1.8, -3.08, 0.0),
       ('A203', '09/05/2014', 1, 24.5, 24.8, 24.5, 95, 95, 95, 23.7, 24.0, 23.7, 1006.9, 1006.9, 1006.3, 0.0, 30, 1.7, -2.78, 0.0),
       ('A203', '09/05/2014', 2, 24.6, 24.6, 24.4, 96, 96, 95, 23.8, 23.8, 23.7, 1006.6, 1006.9, 1006.6, 0.3, 42, 1.7, -2.86, 0.0),
       ('A203', '09/05/2014', 3, 24.8, 25.0, 24.5, 96, 96, 95, 24.1, 24.2, 23.8, 1006.2, 1006.6, 1006.2, 0.0, 51, 1.8, -1.7, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('codigo_estacao', 'S4'), ('data', 'S10'), ('hora', '<i4'), ('temp_inst', '<f8'), ('temp_max', '<f8'), ('temp_min', '<f8'), ('umid_inst', '<i4'), ('umid_max', '<i4'), ('umid_min', '<i4'), ('pto_orvalho_inst', '<f8'), ('pto_orvalho_max', '<f8'), ('pto_orvalho_min', '<f8'), ('pressao', '<f8'), ('pressao_max', '<f8'), ('pressao_min', '<f8'), ('vento_direcao', '<f8'), ('vento_vel', '<i4'), ('vento_rajada', '<f8'), ('radiacao', '<f8'), ('precipitacao', '<f8')])
```

You could still use `loadtxt`, but you'd have to construct your own `dtype`.

```
dtype=[('codigo_estacao', 'S4')... ('precipitacao', '<f8')]
np.loadtxt('stack23785259.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=dtype)
```

You should review the documentation for those functions, and `recarray`.

---

To use `genfromtxt` in the same way, you need to set a couple of parameters:

```
np.genfromtxt('stack23785259.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=None,names=True)
```

`dtype=None` tells it to deduce the field type; `names=True` tell it to take names from the 1st row.

If the dates are in `'2014-09-05'` form (ISO 8601 format), then this `dtype` will read them as `np.datetime64`.  (it also loads all numeric fields as float).

```
dtype([('codigo_estacao', 'S4'), ('data', '<M8[D]'), ('hora', '<f8'), ('temp_inst', '<f8'), ('temp_max', '<f8'), ('temp_min', '<f8'), ('umid_inst', '<f8'), ('umid_max', '<f8'), ('umid_min', '<f8'), ('pto_orvalho_inst', '<f8'), ('pto_orvalho_max', '<f8'), ('pto_orvalho_min', '<f8'), ('pressao', '<f8'), ('pressao_max', '<f8'), ('pressao_min', '<f8'), ('vento_direcao', '<f8'), ('vento_vel', '<f8'), ('vento_rajada', '<f8'), ('radiacao', '<f8'), ('precipitacao', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution here, however, I keep struggling to read the first 2 cols from the file.  My new code is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('SVG')
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

raindata = np.genfromtxt('slz_chuva.txt', float,delimiter=',')
```

And, those 2 cols are essential because they are the name of the stations and the days, respectively.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt('slz_chuva.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=None,names=True)` works like `recfromcsv` in my answer.